# Construct a grammar that generates L = {a^p b^m c^n|n>=0, m>=0, p=m+n}

Tags: grammar, automata

Construct a grammar that generates L:

> **L = {a^p b^m c^n|n>=0, m>=0, p=m+n}**

Till now I have attempted this much:

```
S->A
A->aAb|B
B->aBc|epsilon
```

Is my grammar right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give the mathematical proof, but let's try to enumerate the strings your grammar can produce:

ε, ac, aacc, aaaccc, ... (more same # of a and c), ab, aabb, aaabbb, ... (more same # of a and b), aacb, aaaccb, aaacbb, aaaaccbb, ... (more # a which is the same as # b + c)

Now does:

```
a^p b^m c^n
```

indicate that the order must be strictly fulfilled? i.e. a first then b then c. if yes, you can see yourself that b and c are actually swapped in your grammar.

Comment: Yes the order must be maintained( a followed by b and then c)  How to fix the wrong swapping?

Comment: Ok, Now got it
S->A
A->aAc|B
B->aBb|epsilon

I guess this is the correct grammar.   
Thanks @LeleDumbo